# Pause current stack, log in and resume for Volley when there is a 401

Tags: android, networking, android-volley

I'm currently trying to build a Volley app that handles resuming after a 401-status code.

Say that my application is in a middle of a sync and I receive a 401 error, I'll need to get a new token, I want to pause the current Volley `RequestQueue`, add the failed requests back onto the `RequestQueue`, popup a login display box, and send a login request. Once the server sends me the needed details I will then resume the main `RequestQueue`.

The current solution I'm working on is that my `onErrorResponse` will pause the stack then shows a login box. Send a login request on another `RequestQueue`, wait for a reply and then resume the main `RequestQueue`. But I'm unsure how to restart any failed requests that were failed by the 401 error.

Is this the right direction, if so how can I add my requests back onto the queue from the `onErrorResponse` method?

Comment: i think if you want very nice solution, you must change the source code of volley a bit. add your own sequence numbers to your requests.  after 401 error just find the sequence number of failed one and again resend your requests from that number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set your login request a higher priority than your sync, and set more relaxed retry policies to your sync requests. For example:

```
private class LoginRequest extends com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonObjectRequest {

    ...

    @Override
    public Priority getPriority() {
        return Priority.HIGH;
    }
}
```

and, for your sync requests:

```
public class SyncRequest extends com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonObjectRequest {

    ...    

    @Override
    public Request<?> setRetryPolicy(RetryPolicy retryPolicy) {
        return super.setRetryPolicy(new SyncRetryPolicy());
    }
}


public class SyncRetryPolicy extends com.android.volley.DefaultRetryPolicy {

    private static final int INITIAL_TIMEOUT_MS = 5500;
    private static final int MAX_NUM_RETRIES = 10;
    private static final float BACKOFF_MULTIPLIER = 2f;

    public SyncRetryPolicy() {
        super(INITIAL_TIMEOUT_MS, MAX_NUM_RETRIES, BACKOFF_MULTIPLIER);
    }
}
```

Of course it only makes sense if the user is fast enough to login. In a case where the user just leaves the device in the login screen, you'll need a more robust system.

How important is the sync? Is viable for you to save it in disk for syncing later? And if the user multitask to another app while in the login screen, and the OS decides to deallocate your app from memory?

Comment: This is an interesting solution. So this will continue to retry while the user is logging in. If the user takes too long then eventually it will fail (which is fine). 

The only problem is how do only do the 'SyncRetryPolicy' for 401 errors? I wouldn't want this to happen to the other http status codes.

Comment: Just saw your edit. The sync was just an example. I want everything to resume after logging in. But it isn't a problem if something does fail, say if the user does go away from the app, but I want to avoid it.

Comment: I believe you can get the returned Apache code inside your `Response.ErrorListener()`, by using: 
`public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
    int statusCode = error.networkResponse.statusCode;
}`

Comment: Yep you are correct but not sure how that helps when it comes to restricting the retry policies.

Comment: Can we stop the request queue, until the login request is completed and then start it again once completed?

Comment: This is terrible recommendation. I cannot believe is marked as answer.